# Show a linear endomorphism is invertible, sum of Kernel, and diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So let T : V → V be a linear endomorphism on a vector space over R satisfying $T^2 − 2T − 3I = 0$

a. Show T is invertible.

b. If dimension of V is finite, show $V = K(T − 3I) ⊕ K(T + I)$ and that T is diagonalizable.

Work:

a. $T^2−2T−3I=0$ can be simplified to $(T − 3I)(T + I)=0$ I've read if the eigenvalue of a linear operator with a finite dimension is not $0$ then it is invertible. Does it suffice to say that the eigenvalues here are $3$ and $-1$ so T is invertible?

b. To my understanding it will be diagonalizable if

$dimK(T − 3I) + dim K(T + I)=dim V$

And from here I can say that $V = K(T − 3I) ⊕ K(T + I)$ But again does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

$T^2 − 2T − 3I = 0$ gives $ \frac{(T-2)}{3} \cdot T= T \cdot \frac{(T-2)}{3} = I$, so $T$ is invertible. (This argument also works if $V$ is not finite-dimensional)

For b) note that the minimal polynomial of $T$ must divide $X^2-2X-3 = (X-3)(X+1)$, so the minimal polynomial splits and has only simple roots. This is equivalent to being diagonizable.